# WSO2 InboundEndpoint versus MessageProcessor

Tags: json, jms, wso2-esb

I've define an InboundEndpoint on JMS protocol like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inboundEndpoint suspend="false" protocol="jms" onError="PROCESS_ERROR" sequence="PROCESS" name="SENDER_5M" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<parameters>
    <parameter name="interval">5000</parameter>
    <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.CacheLevel">3</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">application/json</parameter>
    <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.SessionTransacted">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">QUEUE</parameter>
    <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.SessionAcknowledgement">CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.SubscriptionDurable">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType">queue</parameter>
</parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

The sequence "PROCESS" can be very long (several second) so I ask myself if ( as on MessageProcessor with  parameter member.count  ) there is a way to have multi consumer of the queue.

If not, I'll redo my old code with MessageStore/MessageProcessor but I feel more elegant solution with InboundEndpoint as this solution doesn't convert JSON inside ESB and so on avoid some xml/json xml/json transformation problem for the array list on only one element. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In ESB 4.9.0 if you use Message Processor with member.count = 2, then you get two consumers to the JMS queue. Other than that Message Processor solution yields high availability and scalability in a cluster setup. Please refer the blogpost [1] for more details.

Also I am not clear about the xml to JSON conversion and vise versa which you have mentioned here. Please describe it in detail so that I can help you on that matter.